# Import module for all methods of module.exports in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node-modules

I have a node.js module that I want to **export** which contains multiple functions. Many of these functions require a common module, as can be seen in the code below:

```
module.exports = {

    a: function () {
        const util = require("commonModule");
        // Do things
    },

    b: function () {
        const util = require("commonModule");
        // Do other things
    },

    c: function () {
        const util = require("commonModule");
        // Do more other things
    }
}
```

If I did not have this in the module.exports format I could simply do the following and import the module once and it would be available to all functions:

```
const util = require("commonModule");

function a(){
// Do things using commonModule
}

function b(){
// Do other things using commonModule
}
```

Is there a way to modify the module.exports version so that when a user imports my module once it automatically imports commonModule and provides it for all functions rather than having each function call import a new instance of commonModule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to require it in each separate function. You can simply do this:

```
const util = require("commonModule");
module.exports = {

    a: function () {
        // Do things
    },

    b: function () {
        // Do other things
    },

    c: function () {
        // Do more other things
    }
}
```

or if you want, this:

```
const util = require("commonModule");

function a(){
// Do things using commonModule
}

function b(){
// Do other things using commonModule
}

module.exports.a = a;
module.exports.b = b;
```

or even a third way:

```
const util = require("commonModule");

module.exports.a = function (){
// Do things using commonModule
}

module.exports.b = function () {
// Do other things using commonModule
}
```

Which one you choose is up to you.

Comment: If my answer helped you make sure to accept it so others will know that your question is solved.

Comment: I know, it's just I can only accept once the question has been out for 10 mins so as soon as that's up I'll accept it. You were too quick ;D